# Are all my previous prayers invalid?

Tags: salat, mistake

Assalamu alaikum wr wb... I have started to pray this year however I have just realized that when I am sitting in tashahud I have been saying *"assalaamu 'alaynaa ubdillah swalaheen"* instead of *"assalaamu 'alaynaa **wa 'alaa 'ibaadil- laahissaliheen"***.

Would this error make all my previous prayers I made this year invalid? I feel really bad right now and I made dua to Allah swt asking for forgiveness because of this error I have been making in prayer all this time. This is really eating me up inside, I am feeling really regretful for not praying correctly... Is there anything I can do or should I just accept that they will not be accepted by Allah swt?

Comment: No. How do you expect so many prayers to be invalid due to a small mistake?

Comment: Only Allah azzawajjal decides whose prayers are accepted and to what extent. No human has any say in it. Whatever you did in the past was because of your ignorance and it was not deliberate, so rejoice. Allah the mighty doesn't hold people accountable for their unintentional mistakes. Now that you know what is right, make tawba and Dua, then continue praying with the hope of all your prayers being accepted and with the fear that none of your prayers are good enough.even the sahabah were worried that their prayers were not good enough, no one is perfect. All we can do is try our utmost best.